# dlopen/dlsym/dlclose (dlfcn.h) causes memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dlopen

When using the dlfcn family like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int(*timefunc_t)(void*);

int main()
{
    timefunc_t fun;
    void* handle;
    handle = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    fun = (timefunc_t)dlsym(handle, "time");
    printf("time=%d\n", fun(NULL));
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

It causes a Memory leak:

```
==28803== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28803== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28803== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28803== Command: ./dl
==28803== 
time=1309249569
==28803== 
==28803== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28803==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==28803==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 20 bytes allocated
==28803== 
==28803== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28803==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28803==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28803==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28803==    still reachable: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==28803==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28803== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==28803== 
==28803== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28803== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 6)
```

My question is, Is this a programming error, or rather a bug in dlfcn/libdl.so?

Comment: Doesn't valgrind already ship with tons of suppression rules that concern dl-type loading? Run it again with `-v` to see if there's more...

Comment: jmbr's answer is good, but I'd say it's neither a programming error nor a bug in libdl, just the way things are. There's no advantage to trying to cleanup this memory on exit (since it will be destroyed anyway) and in fact it could lead to bugs in multithreaded code (especially with nasty `fork` interaction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the latter. However this does not appear to be a big deal because if you repeat the dlopen/dlsym/dlclose calling another routine you'll see that the memory leak is of the same size, it does not grow with the number of dlopen/dlclose calls.

Comment: Another way of saying this is that a "`O(1)` memory leak" is not a leak but a single drop. :-)